# Enable scrolling when Android soft keyboard is enabled

Tags: android, keyboard, scroll, scrollview

I have PopupWindow where root element is `scrollview` and `EditText` on it (login window). All components are shown and scroll disabled. But when soft keyboard is enabled it hide components under `EditText`. Is it possible enable scrolling when the keyboard is displayed?

Answer (score -1):

Its possible. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android) to know how to detect if a keyboard is visible on your screen.

Once you detect that, just set scrollable property to your layout.

Hope this helps.